# PTS timecode in milliseconds tweak to roll over at 60 seconds?

Tags: ffmpeg, script, mp4, filenames

I'm using FFMPEG to extract images from an MP4. I have a large project where I need to extract a few hundred images. I've cobbled together a working solution from various sites since I'm not an FFMPEG steady user.

I need my file to look like:

```
keyframe-00.01.23.987.png
```

So basically that is 1 minute, 23 seconds, 987 milliseconds.

My string that I put together for FFMPEG to export each frame using milliseconds is:

```
ffmpeg -copyts -i myvideo.mp4 -fps_mode passthrough -r 1000 -f image2 -frame_pts 1 keyframe-%09d.png
```

When it finishes, I have to use Bulk File Rename to insert the decimal points which is a secondary issue but the question at hand is, how do I get it to roll over when the 60 seconds marker is hit?

The PTS in Avidemux rolls over in a time format and I need to have my exported images match that. What I'm getting with that string is:

```
keyframe-000059920.png
keyframe-000059960.png
keyframe-000060040.png
```

I need it to rollover to:

```
keyframe-000100040.png
```

It seems the milliseconds traverse 0-999 and the remaining are all time (60 seconds) rollover based.

If the FFMPEG can't be adjusted, I'm ok with doing it externally, but looking for a tool that can do the conversion for me.

Anyone have any guidance on how to handle this?

Thanks.